# Slack Integration in Laravel, Slack message is redirecting to play store on link on first clicked from the Slack Android app

Tags: laravel-5, slack-api

I have used below code for my Slack integration in Laravel to send messages to Slack group using webhook:

```
array(
"title" => "The following file has been recommended by CreditMate \n Request KJMC review and final decision:",
"title_link" => "http//www.google.com",
"fields" => array(
 array("title" => "Applicant id", "value" => "Test", "short" => false),
array("title" => "Applicant Name", "value" => "Test", "short" => false),
// array("title" => "Application URL", "value" => "http//www.google.com", "short" => false),
array("title" => "test Data", "value" => "", "short" => false),     
"image_url" => "http://www.testimagelink.com",         
                "text" => '',
                "color" => "#7CD197"
            ));
```

While using above code the message are going properly on Slack. In web it is redirecting to the given title link url ie. "http://www.google.com" but in Android Slack app on first click it is redirecting to Play Store and on second click it is redirecting to the given title link URL.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Ok. Can you provide any solution on this.

Answer (score 0):

Check scheme in title_link. There should be a colon right after the protocol.

```
"title_link" => "http://www.google.com"
```